# mcforge: Could not reserve enough space

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, heap-memory, minecraft-forge

I am [getting started](http://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/#customizing-your-mod-information) with minecraft mod development.

If I run ".\gradlew setupDecompWorkspace --stacktrace" to set up my environment, I get the following error:

[image]

As in the tutorial described, I created a file "gradle.properties" and wrote "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2G" into it in order to allocate the ram. Unfortunately that does not solve the problem.

I've gone through some of the stackoverflow answers, which recommend writing -Xmx512m into the gradle.properties file, but that did not help either.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with three steps:

- I completeley removed java from my computer and reinstalled it.
- I added an environment variable: varibale name: _JAVA_OPTIONS value: -Xmx1200M
  [image]
- I added a file gradle.propterties both to root folder **and** .gradle and wrote `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1200M` into it.

One of the last two stps may be redundant, but I am happy it worked for me.